# Odoo, botón no cambia de idioma

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

Importé una traducción a Español en mi Odoo 8. Pero algunos de los botones no cambiaron y siguen en inglés.

Aquí hay un ejemplo:

[image: Spanish Odoo]

Cambié los strings manualmente exportando e importando de nuevo. No sé si eso debe ser cambiado en el código mismo, o en otra parte pero cada vez que subo la traducción, se mantiene en inglés.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: ¿Intentaste sincronizando lo términos? Actualiza los términos en Settings > Translations > Application Terms > Synchronize Terms

Comment: puedes mostrar un poco de tu archivo de traducción?

Comment: @Cesar, si. Ya la actualizacion la intente.

Comment: @Juan, claro, que te gustaria ver del archivo?

Comment: mientras más información puedas mostrar, más fácil será ayudarte.

Comment: Esto es del boton de crear:  
http://screencast.com/t/Hj6N3upLcX
http://screencast.com/t/oTrs46YPTAKM
http://screencast.com/t/rwwdjjSV7
http://screencast.com/t/uX2qtlyoLkqu

Esto para import:
http://screencast.com/t/WryEcwcS3T
http://screencast.com/t/Mu0ttvQz9

No se si esto sera suficiente informacion.

Comment: Este no es un problema de programación. Creo que no es el lugar adecuado para formular esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sincronizar Términos]

Con esta opción lo que haces es actualizar todos los términos (Palabras) de una traducción o un idioma en especifico, con lo cual solucionas el problema.